# Replace NULL using a function

Tags: hadoop, hive

Is there any function to replace NULL or empty space with special character in hive? when I execute the below statement it returns a **semantic exception stating trim works only on string/nvarchar**

```
CASE
 WHEN TRIM(q.address) = '' OR q.address IS NULL THEN '?'
 ELSE q.address END as address
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you paste the larger statement you are trying to execute? What are the data types of the fields in your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LENGTH() to check the length of the column value. It returns > 0, if there is some value else return 0 for empty or NULL value.

Also frame the column value in CASE WHEN ... END block

The final query may look like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LENGTH(address) > 0 THEN address ELSE '?' END AS address
FROM table_name;
```

Please refer [Replace the empty or NULL value with specific value in HIVE query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30285169/replace-the-empty-or-null-value-with-specific-value-in-hive-query-result/30289503#30289503)

Hope this help you!!!

Answer (score 0):

In order to replace nulls you can use Coalesce

```
Coalesce( q.address, '?')
```

But it seems your field adress is not of the proper type to use trim, can you show us the type of that field?